# linear time-constant causal system

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a linear time-constant causal system with the transfer function:
[image]

And I have the insignal [image]

How do I get the output signal?

I thought of Laplace transform the insignal and then get Y and inverse-laplace to get y(t). But I don't know how to laplace transform cos(t) without a Heaviside(t) factor.

Comment: Please consider asking the moderators to move this question to dsp.SE where it is a more natural fit. You can contact the moderators by clicking on the `flag` link below your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transfer function of a dynamical linear system is defined as:

$$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)},$$

where $U(s)$ is the Laplace transform of the input signal. The output signal can therefore  be obtained just as follows:

$$Y(s) = U(s) G(s) = \mathcal{L}_s [\cos{t}] \frac{1}{(s+1)^2},$$ and hence:

> \begin{align}
> \color{blue}{y(t)} = & \mathcal{L}^{-1} [Y(s)] \\ 
> = & \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[  \frac{s}{1+s^2}   \frac{1}{(s+1)^2} \right] \\
> = &\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ -\frac{1}{2 (1+s)^2}+\frac{1}{2 \left(1+s^2\right)} \right] \\ 
> =  & \color{blue}{\left(-\frac{e^{-t} t}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sin{t} \right) H(t)},\end{align}

where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

Note that the Laplace transform of $\sin{t}$ and $\cos{t}$ are tabulated and can be easily found in any textbook.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Is the Laplace transform for sin(t) and sin(t)*Heaviside(t) the same? Because then the in-signal sin(t) would have the same out-signal as sin(t)*Heaviside(t). I can find that sin(t)*Heaviside(t) is tabulated but not sin(t)?

Comment: Yes, it's the same since the Laplace transform is defined as an integral over $t\in [0,\infty)$ (some authors consider $t \in [0^+,\infty)$) and $\sin{t} = \sin{t}H(t)$ for $t>0$, of course.